# Add a Paypal button on the Shopify cart page

Tags: paypal, shopify, cart

I want to move the Paypal button from the Shopify Checkout to the Cart page.

The problem I have is that the Paypal button on the Checkout has a token that's only available on the Checkout page.  I've also checked the Shopify documentation and there is no mention on how to retrieve this token.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the paypal express enabled in payment gateway. This code should let you display the Paypal button in cart page.

```
{% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
   <div class="additional_checkout_buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to your Shopify admin
2. Go to Themes page
3. Click Template Editor
4. Click cart.liquid and open it in online code editor
5. Search for name=”checkout”
6. Please include the following code.

   {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}

   Or Checkout using: 
   {{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}

   {% endif %}
7. Save your changes.

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up